# public double getGPA() method in java

Tags: java, class

```
    public Student getBestStudent( ) {
int best = 0;

for ( int index = 0; index < students.length; index++ ) 
   if ( students[best].getGPA() < students[index].getGPA() )
      best = index;

return students[best];}
public float getGPA ( String name ){
boolean found = false;
int index = 0;
float result;
while ( !found && index < students.length ) {
  if ( students[index].getName().equals( name ) ){
    found = true;
break;}
  index++;}
if ( found ) 
 result = students[index].getGPA();
else
 result = -1f;

return result;}

}
```

And the error is:

```
error cannot find symbol line -> result = students[index].getGPA();
error cannot find symbol line -> if ( students[best].getGPA() < students[index].getGPA() )
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: This is not a good question. StackOverflow isn't for just posting your broken code. You have to actually demonstrate understanding of the problem, describe attempts to solve it, and __ask an actual question__

Comment: I am sorry for my question I am a new user at this site

Comment: That's OK. We all have to start somewhere. At least it looks like you're getting some reasonable answers. When you get a chance, please poke around in the help documents. They're actually quite good.

Comment: I will consider after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means your getGPA() method is not a method of students[index]. 
See of what class that students[index] object is, and see if it 
has getGPA() method. And try to format properly your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your getGPA method requires a parameter of type String. In your if statement, you are directly calling your getGPA method with no parameters.

You either need o have  a getGPA() method with no parameters or change the if statement to pass the required parameters.